# Adding Sort, Pagination and filtering to ASP.NET Api

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, pagination, filtering

Can you explain to me how to add sort, filtering and paging to my ASP.NET Web API, so I could write url like this

```
http://localhost:8000/api/Meetings?sort_by=name&sort_type=asc&s=Joh&page=1&page_size=3
```

I have this `MeetingsController`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication3.Models;

namespace WebApplication3.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/Meetings")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MeetingsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly MeetingContext _context;

        public MeetingsController(MeetingContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        //GET: api/Meetings
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Meeting>>> GetMeetings()
        {
            return await _context.Meetings.ToListAsync();
        }

        // GET: api/Meetings/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Meeting>> GetMeeting(string id)
        {
            var meeting = await _context.Meetings.FindAsync(id);

            if (meeting == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return meeting;
        }

        // PUT: api/Meetings/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutMeeting(string id, Meeting meeting)
        {
            if (id != meeting.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(meeting).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!MeetingExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        // POST: api/Meetings
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Meeting>> PostMeeting(Meeting meeting)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Guid obj = Guid.NewGuid();
                meeting.Id = obj.ToString();
                _context.Meetings.Add(meeting);
            }

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (MeetingExists(meeting.Id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetMeeting), new { id = meeting.Id }, meeting);
        }

        // DELETE: api/Meetings/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Meeting>> DeleteMeeting(string id)
        {
            var meeting = await _context.Meetings.FindAsync(id);

            if (meeting == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Meetings.Remove(meeting);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return meeting;
        }

        private bool MeetingExists(string id)
        {
            return _context.Meetings.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it:

this is only a sample:

```
 //GET: api/Meetings
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Meeting>>> GetMeetings(string sort_by, string sort_type, string s, int page , int page_size)
        {
            IQueryable<Meeting> query = _context.Meetings;
            switch (sort_by)
            {
                case "name":
                    if (sort_type == "asc")
                    {
                        query = query.orderby(c => c.name);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(c => c.name);
                    }

                    break;
                case "surname":
                    if (sort_type == "asc")
                    {
                        query = query.orderby(c => c.surname);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        query = query.OrderByDescending(c => c.surname);
                    }

                    break;
                     //do more


            }
            //your search 
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
            {
           
                query = query.where(c => c.name.Contains(s));
            }




            return await query.Skip((page - 1)* page_size).Take(page_size).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Comment: You could maybe add a model to avoid having each parameter separated.

Comment: @Arcord he/she want to filter by query string like this: http://localhost:8000/api/Meetings?sort_by=name&sort_type=asc&s=Joh&page=1&page_size=3

Comment: I get an error with ToListAsync(), IEnumerable<Meeting> doesn't contain a definition for 'ToListAsync()'

Comment: You can still use a model, you just need to use the "[FromQuery]" attribute in front of the parameter to warn the model binder the data will come from the query parameters.

Comment: @Aska i change this line try it: IQueryable<Meeting> query = _context.Meetings;

Comment: @foadabd I tried to get my data by localhost:44329/api/Meetings?sort_by=name&sort_type=asc but it didn't show anything

Comment: @foadabd if I want to get something I should type all the parameters? What if I want only to sort data and get it all

Comment: @Aska check by page and page_size cause default is zero and return zero item

Comment: @foadabd this url doesn't work either https://localhost:44329/api/Meetings&sort_by=name&sort_type=asc&page=1&page_size=1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229318/discussion-between-aska-and-foadabd).

Comment: @foadabd how can I write search so it will search for value not only in c.name but in all fields?

Comment: @Aska it can be new question but you can write your search by OR(||) linq query